# Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type when using connection.executemany()

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, sqlite

I can't seem to make the `.executemany()` statement of SQLite work.

#### Statement I'd like to execute

```py
connection = sqlite3.connect(connectionString)
with connection:
    connection.executemany('''INSERT INTO Marketrecords (DateTime, Symbol_ID, Open, High, Low, Close, Volume)
                              VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', [marketRecords])
```

#### Data I'd like to write

```py
marketRecords = [
    ('DateTime', str(dataframe['Timestamp'])),
    ('Symbol_ID', int(symbolValue)),
    ('Open', float(dataframe['Open'])),
    ('High', float(dataframe['High'])),
    ('Low', float(dataframe['Low'])),
    ('Close', float(dataframe['Close'])),
    ('Volume', float(dataframe['Volume']))
]
```

```py
dataframeColumns = [
    ('Timestamp', <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>)
    ('Open', <class 'numpy.float64'>)
    ('High', <class 'numpy.float64'>)
    ('Low', <class 'numpy.float64'>)
    ('Close', <class 'numpy.float64'>)
    ('Volume', <class 'numpy.float64'>)
]
```

#### How the table looks

```
CREATE TABLE Marketrecords (
        Record_ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
        DateTime TEXT NOT NULL,
        Symbol_ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
        Open REAL NOT NULL,
        High REAL NOT NULL,
        Low REAL NOT NULL,
        Close REAL NOT NULL,
        Volume REAL NOT NULL
        )
```

#### The error I get

```py
connection.executemany("INSERT INTO Marketrecords VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", [marketRecords])
sqlite3.InterfaceError: Error binding parameter 0 - probably unsupported type.
```

#### What parameter 0 looks like

```py
print(type(marketRecords[0]))
<class 'tuple'>
print(type(marketRecords[0][0]))
<class 'str'>
print(type(marketRecords[0][1]))
<class 'str'>
```

Where am I going wrong? Been on this for hours..

Comment: `executemany` takes tuples of values only, not name / value pairs. But more fundamentally, you likely want [pandas.DataFrame.to_sql](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html#pandas-dataframe-to-sql) instead.

Comment: @tdelaney ```print(type(marketRecords[0]))``` tells me that the first item in the marketRecords list is, in fact, a tuple (added this to the post, thanks for your input!). However, I just learned about ```pandas.DataFrame.to_sql``` from you.

Comment: `('DateTime', str(dataframe['Timestamp']))` is a tuple with two values, the name of the field "DateTime", and a value (the str representation of the Timestamp column). Your insert wants `(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)` - 7 values. You need a tuple of 7 values and no field names. If you wanted, say, the first row, it would be tuple of `(str(dataframe['Timestamp'][0]`, ...etc)`.